# python xlrd - loop through excel cells to find extent of data

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I've benn trying to find a way to extract data from a list of excel files, I've been able to load the workbook, select the sheet and extract from a certain cell, but I'm having problems because the files are not formatted a databases, more like a repetition of instances of descriptions, the thing is, I need to find a way to get the number of repetitions of the instances to extract a cerrtain cell in each something like this:

[image]

Some files have one instance, other 5 or 6, I tried a while loop, but it didnt seems to work:

```
import xlrd
from os import listdir, chdir

dir = chdir"r"/home/fcr/anaconda3/envs/Arch/calam")

lista = []

for arc in listdir(dir):
    x = xlrd.open_workbook(arc)
    sh = x.sheet_by_index(0)
    for r in range(4, 500, 18):
        v = sh.cell(r, 10).value
        while v != " "
            lista.append(v)

print(lista)
```

now I'm trying an if statement in which i divide the total rows by the separation between the cells (18, to find the number of repetitions, but it seems that im missing something

```
import xlrd
from os import listdir, chdir

dir = chdir"r"/home/fcr/anaconda3/envs/Arch/calam")

lista = []

for arc in listdir(dir):
    x = xlrd.open_workbook(arc)
    sh = x.sheet_by_index(0)
    tram = int(sh.rows/17)
    c3 = []
    if tram > 1 and tram < 2:
        v = sh.cell(4, 10).value
        c3.append(v)
    if tram > 2 and tram < 3:
        v = sh.cell(4, 10).value
        j = sh.cell(22, 10).value
        c3.append(v)
        c3.append(j)
    if tram > 3 and tram < 4:
        v = sh.cell(4, 10).value
        j = sh.cell(22, 10).value
        h = sh.cell(40, 10).value
        c3.append(v)
        c3.append(j)
        c3.append(h)
    else:
        print("x")
    print(c3)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, if it's useful for anyone, looping according to the sheet rows, then writing it to a excel file:

```
import xlrd
from os import listdir, chdir
from openpyxl import Workbook


dir = chdir(r"/home/fcr/anaconda3/envs/002/Arch/cal")

lista = []

for arc in listdir(dir):
    x = xlrd.open_workbook(arc)
    sh = x.sheet_by_index(0)
    ntram = sh.nrows
    for r in range(4, ntram, 18):
        call = []
        v = sh.cell(r, 10).value
        tram = sh.cell(r-1, 0).value
        cini = sh.cell(r-1, 1).value
        cterm = sh.cell(r-1, 2).value
        npist = sh.cell(r-1, 5).value
        call.append(arc.strip(".xlsx"))
        call.append(v)
        call.append(tram)
        call.append(cini)
        call.append(cterm)
        call.append(npist)
        lista.append(call)


print(lista)

columns = ["CALLE",  "IND_SERV", "TRAMO", "CALL_INI", "CALL_TER",     "NUM_PIST"]

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

sheet.append(columns)

for pe in lista:
    sheet.append(pe)

book.save(r"/home/fcr/anaconda3/envs/002/Arch/LisCal.xlsx")
```